# ASP.NET next / previous wizard control

Tags: asp.net, gallery, wizard-control

I'm trying to show 6 different covers of an online magazine for a site I'm working on and wanted to use something like the wizard tool I've made below. I'm new to ASP so I'm not to sure what I'll need to do for the last issue to only show a previous button.

The start shows just next and the 2,3,4 and 5 show previous and next, but 6 only shows a next and there's no where to go so it gets stuck

I've added my code below, any help would be great:

ASP Wizard Control

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" ActiveStepIndex="0">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" StepType="Start" title="Issue1">
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Issue2">
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Issue3">
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Issue4">
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Issue5">
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Issue6" StepType="Start">
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you've explicitly specified that StepType="Start" for your last step, remove this line of code from *Issue6* and it will no longer display the Next button.However, when you do this you will notice that the last step will now display two buttons:

1) Previous

2) Finish

This is by design as the Wizard control's purpose is to collect data from user by separating it into logical chunks, making data collection more intuitive and submiting the data to the server for processing at the **last step**.If you only want to display a previous button on the last step I would suggest using a [MultiView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_views.htm) control

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I just gave FinishCompleteButtonStyle a display:none and its now working how I wanted. Many thanks